# Laravel many to many fetching data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am a laravel greenhorn and I am going nuts. Well, maybe I am starring too long on that project.
I'm stucked in the following situation:

I am building a "diary" for enterprises. My tables from my database are below.

My target is, that only users within the same enterprise can see the reports related to their enterprise. So in my reportController I have following lines in my index method:

```
$enterpriseId = Auth::user()->enterprise_id;
$enterpriseProjects = Enterprise::find($enterpriseId)->projects()->get();
$enterprises = Enterprise::find($enterpriseId);
foreach ($enterprises->projects as $key => $pivotTableProject) {
      $reports = Report::where('project_id', $pivotTableProject->pivot->project_id)->get();
}

return view('reports.index')->with('reports', $reports);
```

As expected I get only one entry from my database. How can I fetch all for the same enterprise? If I put the reports in an array I get this (with dd):

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Collection {#250 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▶]
  }
  1 => Collection {#239 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▶]
  }
]
```

But I need a collection with one array and the reports inside there. 
Can anyone help a desperated laravel newbie?

Thanks in advance.
[Image of database part here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlVvK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem yesterday with these lines: In my ReportController 
`$usersEnterpriseId = Auth::user()->enterprise_id; $enterprises = Enterprise::find($usersEnterpriseId); 
foreach ($enterprises->projects as $pivotTableProject) { 
   $reports[] = Report::where('project_id', $pivotTableProject->pivot->project_id)->get(); 
}`

And in my view I am showing the results via 2 foreach-loops (of course not the best solution, but it works for me). Thanks for your help @HasilT. You pushed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to achieve this, Here is one solution. 
It is only a code snippet(not a complete solution. I have some trouble setting up a system like you are building).

The way I implemented it, is using constrained nested eager loading of relations.

```
$reports = Report::with([
        'project' => function ($project) use ($enterpriseId) {
            return $project->with([
                'enterprise_project' => function ($enterprise_project) use ($enterpriseId) {
                    return $enterprise_project->with([
                        'enterprise'=>function($enterprise) use($enterpriseId){
                            return $enterprise->where('id', $enterpriseId);
                        }
                    ]);
                }
                ]);
            }
            ])->get();
```

For this solution to work I assume you have

- `project` method in your `Report` model which connects the `Project` Model.
- `enterprise_project` method in `Project` model which connects the db table `enterprise_project`.
- `enterprise` method in your `enterprise_project` model which connects to `enterprise` table/model in your db.

If it is hard to follow above code or any confusions please read constraining eager loads section in laravel doc([link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads))

PS: If there is anything wrong with the code, feel free to comment/edit the answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I will try that today and read about eager loading. I thought I can go with `$enterpriseProjects = Enterprise::find($enterpriseId)->projects()->get();` because I get the projects for the user's enterprise. I only have to "connect" that with the reports.